# ASP.NET Web API on IIS 6: HTTP Status Code 500 Internal Server Error 

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-4.0, iis-6, windows-server-2003

Since i don't have any more details despite custom errors off and debug on, i don't have much more to say. Here are some points of interest:

- Regular ASP.NET MVC /controller/action URLs work on iis 6
- I've added wildcard isapi filter to iis 6 although i think it is not needed in .net 4
- WebAPIs work on local IISExpress server so it shouldn't be a serialization error

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem? If not, at least it would be nice to find a way to have more detailed error messages.

Comment: Have you checked the event log (if you can)

Comment: i haven't, i will see if there's any details there

Comment: Here's the log:
cs-method:GET, cs-uri-stem:/templex/api/parse, cs-uri-query:expression='test' ,s-port:80 ,cs(User-Agent):Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/536.11+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/20.0.1132.47+Safari/536.11, status:500, substatus:0, win32status:0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never found how to fix my problem but I ended up working around the problem by running a WebAPI self host service in the same server, and it works perfectly.
All the documentation you need to make it happen is here:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/self-host-a-web-api